# pythonでモジュールのimportエラーになるため、モジュールを特定の場所（/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages）にインストールしたい

Tags: python, numpy, import

pythonスクリプト内で`import numpy`が`ModuleNotFoundError`でできず、解決方法を考えています。
sys.pathを出力すると、`/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages`が含まれています。
また、`pip list`で表示されるリストにはnumpyが含まれますが、`pip show numpy`ではlocationが`/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages`となっています。

試行錯誤の結果、`brew info python`の実行結果に

```
You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

とあったので`pip3 install numpy`としましたが、

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.26.2)
```

と出力されてしまいました。
`python3 -V`の実行結果が`3.11.5`であることからも、`/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages`にnumpyをインストールすると解決できると考えましたが、この方法が正しいかどうか分からず質問させて頂いています。
この方法で解決できる場合はモジュールのインストール先を指定する方法も教えて頂きたいです。
ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もしも疑問に思う部分が解決できないのであれば, 質問を直すか, (必要なら)回答にコメントつけるかしてください。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python3` コマンドと `pip3` コマンドがそれぞれ別環境を指してるように見えます
(複数の Python環境があり, `pip3` は別の環境なのでしょう)

- `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/`
- `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/`

(どこか特定のディレクターという訳ではないが)
`python3` コマンドの環境に Python モジュールをインストールするなら 以下のようにできます

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install SomePackage

$ python3 -m pip install SomePackage==1.0.4    # specific version

# 質問の numpy での場合
$ python3 -m pip install numpy
```

参考: (docs.python.org) [Python モジュールのインストール](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/installing/)