# Mac(M1) pythonのimportエラーを解決したい。

Tags: python, macos, import

プログラム勉強し始めの初心者です。
エクセルを操作する簡単なプログラムをmacで作りたいので、スクリプトを書きたいのですが、xlrdのライブラリがimportできなくて困っています。
一応自分で調べてsys.path等でパスを調べたのですが、よくわからず？すいませんが何が悪いのかご教授頂きたいです。
申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

```
(base) o.mitsue@OMmac2021 create-communication-list % /usr/bin/python3 "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/python_Development/create-communi
cation-list/main.py"
['/Volumes/Extreme SSD/python_Development/create-communication-list',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
(base) o.mitsue@OMmac2021 create-communication-list % pip show xlrd  
Name: xlrd
Version: 2.0.1
Summary: Library for developers to extract data from Microsoft Excel (tm) .xls spreadsheet files
Home-page: http://www.python-excel.org/
Author: Chris Withers
Author-email: chris@withers.org
License: BSD
Location: /Users/o.mitsue/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかも。[Pythonでimportの対象ディレクトリのパスを確認・追加（sys.pathなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-import-module-search-path/), [\[備忘録\]anaconda&VScodeでpythonのimportエラーに手こずった話](https://qiita.com/pagu_19/items/2b06a38317f307bfc9a7), [pythonでモジュールのimportエラーになるため、モジュールを特定の場所（/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages）にインストールしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/96835/26370)

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
調べてpythonのインタープリタの設定が違っておりました。
インタープリターを設定を変更したらimportできるようになりました。

Answer (score -1):

cubick♦様の回答で解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: こちらは回答欄ですので、解決に至った具体的な手順を書かれると良いかと思います。お礼のコメントは質問のコメント欄に書かれると良いかと思います。